# How can I send strings in a text file one by one, with a second delay?

Tags: python, string, file, sockets

I got a client-server connection which encrypts the strings from a text file. The clients opens the .txt file, encrypts those strings and sends them to the server. I got 3 strings in the .txt file and want to send the encrypted strings one by one to the server.

So what it should look like is that client sends X string (waits 1 second before sending Y string) and in the meanwhile, the server returns the decrypted string back to the client. 
This is what I got to send the data over a socket

```py
inFile = open("textinput.txt", "rb")
content = inFile.read()
inFile.close()

enc_data = publickey.encrypt(content, 16)

ipaddr = "127.0.0.1"
portnr = 11200

connectie = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connectie.connect((ipaddr, portnr))
connectie.send(enc_data[0])#send encrypted data
```

`content`contains the 3 strings and `enc_data` contains the 3 strings, but encrypted. I send `enc_data` over to the server with `connectie.send`

How would I be able to send those strings individually with a delay of 1 second?

Comment: Do you have server and client sockets defined in same file/module?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest What do you mean exactly? I have 2 files, client.py and server.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demonstrated on simplified custom encryption/decryption approach (using `simple-crypt` library):

Sample `input.txt` contents:

```
first line
second line
last line
```

---

**`server.py`** :

```
import socket
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
POST = 11200

pwd = 'secret' # for demo only

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind((HOST, POST))
    sock.listen(1)

    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f'Got connection from {addr}')
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(f'Received data from client {data}')
            conn.send(decrypt(pwd, data))
```

**`client.py`** :

```
import socket
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
POST = 11200

pwd = 'secret' # for demo only

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST, POST))
    with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            sock.send(encrypt(pwd, line.strip()))
            time.sleep(1)   # the needed delay
            data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
            print(f'Received data from server "{data}"')
```

---

Socket server process run and output:

```
[roman@roman-pc data]$ python3 server.py
Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 40736)
Received data from client b"sc\x00\x02p\x02\x98\xd4@\x9e\xeaeb@u\xc5\xbc\x0b\xbea\xcf\xca~\x87\xb1\x01(\x9d\xd2\x05\x0b8\xa8\x85\x94\xc4\xc5\xe2W\x8d\xe5P\xec\x83D\xeb\xe8\xcbV\x1ai3\xf5\x13s\x82\xbe7\xc9\xa8\xad'e\xbeq&Q_\x0f\t~V\x13\xe9\xde\xf1\xba~"
Received data from client b'sc\x00\x02Sa\xe9\x97,\xf7\x99\x7f<\xd2n\xbfc\x98g~t\xa3\xf9\x98\xc9\xf9\xff>\x99\x9aI{sAMY"\x9bX\x19\xfe\xe3i\xad=\xfa\rs\x9b,\xaadN\xb9_Bc\xe2\xf75\xdfP/wx\x1a\x91\xa27VZ[M\xa3\x0f3\xc9vL'
Received data from client b'sc\x00\x02U\xb8\xbc|\xbb\xbe\x95\xd5\\}0}\x8a\x10^]\xa0\xc9S\x08a\x99\x8e\xdd7[\xa4q\xec|\xe3\xe1\xf9|\xca?\x07\x18\xbc\xb4^*`\x7f\x07)\x1b\x10&\xda\xfdl!O\xa5K\xbe.\xd4\xbe\xb0\x960\x81\x83\xcb\x07\xb0=\x95\x8f\xd5\xb5'
```

Socket client process run and output (sends encrypted message with the needed delay):

```
[roman@roman-pc data]$ python3 client.py
Received data from server "first line"
Received data from server "second line"
Received data from server "last line"
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your amazing answer. This answers exactly what I was stuck on. However this is the format I receive the decrypted strings on the client.  `Ontvangen gedecrypte strings in hoofdletters:
GEHEIME BERICHT 1PROJECT PADWACHTWOORDEN` this is how I print: `print("\nOntvangen gedecrypte strings in hoofdletters:\n" +str(decrypt_data.decode('utf-8')))
` How would I be able to fix this. It should be like GEHEIME BERICHT 1\nPROJECT PAD\nWACHTWOORDEN

Comment: @fire2247z, `\n` is a linebreak sign which will shift the text next to it to the next line. To preserve those signs you need to either 1) escape those with additional backslash `GEHEIME BERICHT 1\\nPROJECT PAD\nWACHTWOORDEN ` or 2) wrap into `repr` function: `print("\nOntvangen gedecrypte strings in hoofdletters:\n" + repr(decrypt_data.decode('utf-8')))`

Comment: I think I've said it wrong, I want the client output to look like yours. GEHEIME BERICHT 1 should be on line 1, PROJECT PAD on line 2 etc.. I tried using strip() and your method. Nothing seems to solve it.

Comment: @fire2247z, I've posted a working approach/solution. What you are asking additionally is related to your specifics of representation of your custom data - that's another question (you may create it on SO).

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Could you explain what `with conn:` does?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a reliable protocol. Since TCP does not necessarily preserve any boundaries, it is incorrect to assume that `conn.recv(1024)` on the server side will return exactly the bytes object that `sock.send(encrypt(pwd, line.strip()))` sends. And the same thing holds for the data going in the other direction.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, No, you got confused. socket should receive and send `bytes`. In the case I shown `encrypt/decrypt` functions always return data as `as bytes`

Comment: I understand that, but that isn't the point. The point is that, for example, `sock.send(encrypt(pwd, line.strip()))` may send 64 bytes but `data = conn.recv(1024)` may only receive 63 bytes. When you try decrypting the 63 bytes it will fail.